Problem with docker-compose between Springboot and MySql, error executing DDL
I am developing a small application using springboot with maven and a mysql db. I created a Dockerfile that's working and the docker-compose seems to start but an error occur:

Error executing DDL "create table acquisti (id integer not null
auto_increment, data_acquisto datetime not null, email varchar(255)
not null, id_scheda integer not null, token varchar(255) not null,
primary key (id)) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

the same happen for every entity present
here my docker-compose
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: jayaz98/angelodaleotest:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/angelodaleoptdb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: docker-mysql
      DATABASE_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: angelodaleoptdb
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      timeout: 5s

Entities
AcquistiEntity
package it.angeloDaleoPt.project.entity;


import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;


@Entity
@Table(name = "acquisti")
@Data
public class AcquistiEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "id_scheda", nullable = false)
    private Integer idScheda;

    @Column(name = "token", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String token;

    @Column(name = "data_acquisto", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime dataAcquisto;



}


AppuntamentoEntity
package it.angeloDaleoPt.project.entity;


import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "appuntamento")
@Data
public class AppuntamentoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "cognome", nullable = false)
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name = "sesso", nullable = false)
    private String sesso;

    @Column(name = "num_telefono", nullable = false)
    private String numTelefono;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "eta", nullable = false)
    private Integer eta;

    @Column(name = "anni_esperienza", nullable = false)
    private Integer anniEsperienza;

    @Column(name = "esperienza_app_calorie", nullable = false)
    private String esperienzaAppCalorie;

    @Column(name = "num_allenamenti", nullable = false)
    private Integer numAllenamenti;

    @Column(name = "ore_allenamento", nullable = false)
    private Integer oreAllenamento;

    @Column(name = "problemi_fisici", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String problemiFisici;

    @Column(name = "ciclo_regolare", nullable = false)
    private String cicloRegolare;

    @Column(name = "dieta", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "MEDIUMTEXT")
    private String dieta;

    @Column(name = "allenamento", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "MEDIUMTEXT")
    private String allenamento;

    @Column(name = "personal", nullable = false)
    private String personal;
}


PrimadopoEntity
package it.angeloDaleoPt.project.entity;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;


import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "primadopo")
public class PrimadopoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "percorso", nullable = false)
    private String percorso;

    @Column(name = "data_inserimento")
    private LocalDateTime dataInserimento;

}


SchedaEntity
package it.angeloDaleoPt.project.entity;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "scheda")
@Data
public class SchedaEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "titolo", nullable = false)
    private String titolo;

    @Column(name = "descrizione", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String descrizione;

    @Column(name = "autore", nullable = false)
    private String autore;

    @Column(name = "prezzo", nullable = false)
    private String prezzo;

    @Column(name = "pathcopertina")
    private String pathcopertina;

}


the problem is that the error does not describe the problem (or maybe I don't see it). However, in local it works
